# Is it safe to host passwordless web applications/software with web GUI in Virtual Machines

Tags: network, linux, firewalls, virtualization

I have a Linux Mint Virtual Machine which I use quite a lot with my Windows host. I have lots of Software installed there (mostly with web GUI so I can access them from host easily).

So I am wondering instead of securing individual applications (by adding username/password, limit incoming request from host IP), can I just add a firewall which will limit incoming requests only from host IP? Will it be safe?

Answer (score 1):

Using either the Windows (host) firewall or the guest OS firewall to do that is not recommended.

All VM tools already provide that kind of control. Have a look at the different types of networking available. You want a host-only network. By design that can only be used between the host and the VM, it is never accessible outside the host.

I should also have said that if you also need some services to reach outside the host, you can have both by setting up 2 networks and binding your web services to the host-only network.

Comment: I *think* OP was asking about a client OS firewall.

Comment: Good point! Though of course, the answer is still the same. Wrong tool and not needed. Adds too much complexity when all you need to do is change the networking. I should also have said that if you also need some services to reach outside the host, you can have both by setting up 2 networks and binding your web services to the host-only network.

Comment: You can edit your answer to include that.

Comment: @NeilSmithline Yes! I was indeed talking about the guest OS firewall.

Comment: Updated slightly to include that, sorry for not reading the question properly. The answer is the same thankfully :)

Comment: Can I ask (just curious), why it is not recommended to use guest OS firewall? How it can go wrong?

Comment: @varunagw, I don't think that there's a problem with the the guest firewall, it is just more likely to be misconfigured or something. Also, a malicious program on your guest may be able to disable the firewall but not likely reconfigure the VM network configuration.

Comment: That is correct. Why over complicate things, simple is generally best and most secure. Also, the guest firewall takes up resources that you don't need.